# Simplex algorithm with tableau

Tags: discrete-mathematics, optimization, linear-programming, simplex

\begin{array}{c|c|cc}
\hline
\text{BV}& \text{value} & x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & x_4 & x_5 & x_6\\ \hline
 x_4 & 8& 2& 3 & 2 & 1 & 0& 0\\ 
 x_5 & 8 &4 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 
 x_6 & 4 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\ \hline
 -z  & 0 & 2 & b & 0.5 & 0 & 0 & 0\\\hline
\end{array}

Above you can see the tableau representation of a linear program with a coefficient $b\in \mathbb{R}$. BV stands for basic variable.

> For which $b$ is $y_1 = \frac12, y_2 = \frac14, y_3 = 0$ a optimal
> solution of the Dual program of this primal program shown in the
> tableau?

The strong duality property says that the optimal value of the primal and its Dual program are the same. And the optimal value is $z=8\cdot\frac{1}{2}+8\cdot \frac{1}{4}+4\cdot0=6$. So when I do the primal simplex algorithm of the tableau below, in the end $-z$ has to be $-6$. I did the simplex and got the solution $b=2$.
But I think my way is eiher wrong or too long. Can anybody help for a fast way to the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is complementary slackness condition.  Let me state the primal problem for clarity.

\begin{align*}
  & \max (2,b,0.5) (x_1,x_2,x_3)^T \\
  & \mbox{s.t.}
  \begin{pmatrix}
    2 & 3 & 2 \\
    4 & 2 & 1 \\
    1 & 1 & 1
  \end{pmatrix}
  \begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{pmatrix}
  \le \begin{pmatrix}8\\8\\4\end{pmatrix} \tag{P} \\
  & x_1,x_2,x_3 \ge 0 \\
  & \min (8,8,4) (y_1,y_2,y_3)^T \\
  & \mbox{s.t.}
  \begin{pmatrix}
    2 & 4 & 1 \\
    3 & 2 & 1 \\
    2 & 1 & 1
  \end{pmatrix}
  \begin{pmatrix}y_1\\y_2\\y_3\end{pmatrix}
  \ge \begin{pmatrix}2\\b\\0.5\end{pmatrix} \tag{D} \\
 & y_1,y_2,y_3 \ge 0
\end{align*}

The variables $x_1,x_2,x_3,y_1,y_2,y_3$ are called structual variables.  We add slack and surplus variables to the primal problem and its dual so as to transform the above LPPs into their standard form.  I write them out for clarity.

\begin{align*}
  & \max (2,b,0.5) (x_1,x_2,x_3)^T & \\
  & \mbox{s.t.}
  \begin{pmatrix}
    2 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    4 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1
  \end{pmatrix}
  \begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\\x_4\\x_5\\x_6\end{pmatrix}
  = \begin{pmatrix}8\\8\\4\end{pmatrix} \tag{P} \\
  & x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5,x_6 \ge 0 \\
  & \min (8,8,4) (y_1,y_2,y_3)^T \\
  & \mbox{s.t.}
  \begin{pmatrix}
    2 & 4 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
    3 & 2 & 1 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
    2 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -1
  \end{pmatrix}
  \begin{pmatrix}y_1\\y_2\\y_3\\y_4\\y_5\\y_6\end{pmatrix}
  = \begin{pmatrix}2\\b\\0.5\end{pmatrix} \tag{D} \\
  & y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4,y_5,y_6 \ge 0
\end{align*}

The variables $x_4,x_5,x_6$ are called primal slack variables, and $y_4,y_5,y_6$ are called dual surplus variables.  The complementary slackness condition states that $(x_1,x_2,x_3)(y_4,y_5,y_6)^T = (x_4,x_5,x_6)(y_1,y_2,y_3)^T = 0$.

\begin{align*}
  &\because x_1,\dots,x_6,y_1,\dots,y_6 \ge 0 \\
  &\therefore x_1 y_4 = x_2 y_5 = x_3 y_6 = x_4 y_1 = x_5 y_2 = x_6 y_3 = 0
\end{align*}

Since it's given that $(y_1,y_2,y_3) = (\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4},0)$, we can use the standard form (or even from the canonical form) to compute the dual surplus variables $(y_4,y_5,y_6) = (0,2-b,\frac{5}{4})$.  Therefore, $x_3 = x_4 = x_5 = 0$.  If $y_5 \ne 0$, then $x_2 = 0$.  Then it can be easily seen from the standard (or canonical form) that it's impossible. (Only $x_1$ and $x_6$ are left, and $2 x_1 = 8 = 4 x_1$, which is false.)  Hence $y_5 = 0 \iff b = 2$.